# Outlets and buttons ignored

Tags: iphone, interface, builder, action

My problem is that I cannot access any of the controls in a view defined using interface builder. This is the .h code for the Navigation bar (as an example):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *tTitle;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UINavigationBar *tTitle;
@end
```

The implementation (.m) is:

```
#import "myController.h"

@implementation myController
@synthesize tTitle;

- (void)dealloc {
    [tTitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    tTitle.topItem.title=@"This is my title";
}
```

In viewDidLoad tTitle (and my other outlets) are always 0x0. I have omitted the two text fields and the button for brevity.

This exact code works in another view in the app without issue. In IB I right click on the file owner icon and it shows my outlets correctly (and the single button action). Yet at run time - nada. I click the button and no response. The title is still the default title. I cannot set the text fields text property because the fields are all 0x0.

The view is linked to the view controller. As near as I can tell everything is identical between the two views that are doing the same thing. Obviously something is awry, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you connecting the various items in Interface Builder to the outlets in the class? (Right or control click on the interface element and then drag a line to the class - a popup of the defined outlets should appear and you can then select the correct one.)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, if I right click on the control it shows that it is connected correctly (as a referenced outlet) and if I right click on the file owner icon it shows all my outlets and button connected where they should be.

Comment: I see that you are saying the code works fine in another view. Are you trying to reuse the same nib file for both ViewController's?

Comment: Negative. I am using two different nib files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I did the ROI and figured it would be easier to delete and recreate the view (one control at a time) in an attempt to see where it was going awry. The answer is the title bar title set worked from the get-go. I have no idea why the other class didn't work. But discretion is the better part of valor in this situation. The new class is working fine. Thanks for everyone's input.